# Dúvida de iniciante biblioteca javax.imageio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estou tentando fazer este import no java studio

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;
```

mas está-me a aparecer este erro:

> cannot resolve symbol'ImageIO'

Como posso resolver isto?

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que essa classe não é suportada para Android. Caso você tente procurar essa classe no [Developer.Android](http://developer.android.com/), verá que ela não aparece.

Segundo [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693011/) pergunta feita no SOen, você pode usar a classe [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html).